# Unable to run gnuplot on Ubuntu WSL2 - cannot connect to display

Tags: gui, windows-subsystem-for-linux, gnuplot

I have installed gnuplot on Ubuntu with `sudo apt install gnuplot-x11`, then installed `vcxsrv` on Windows and run it: [vcxsrv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SoNu.png)

I would then expect that running gnuplot from bash and typing `plot sin(x)` would produce me a graph, however I receive this error: [gnuplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LL0YX.png)

I should add that I have added those options to zshrc:

```
export QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1
export QT_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/lib/qt/plugins
export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0
export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=Yes
```

I have tried many options and solutions, but with no success. Would be very glad for help

Comment: Have you run any basic diagnostics such as `xdpyinfo | head`?

Comment: @steeldriver ran it, log shows only: `xdpyinfo:  unable to open display "localhost:0.0"`

Comment: ... so it's not a problem with gnuplot specifically... either the vcxsrv isn't running on the host, or is running on a different display, or something in Windows is preventing X clients from connecting to it... I'm not sure what to suggest beyond that

Answer (score 0):

for the records, if anyone else is looking at running gnuplot with wsl2, it is working fine in Win11 which runs gnuplot without the need for X windows (i.e. vcxsrv or similar).

Comment: Lots of improvements wsl > win 11. Very exciting!

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 10, the problem was almost certainly the:

```
export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0
```

WSL2 runs in it's own virtual network, so `localhost` is the WSL2 instance itself.  Windows IP address is different, and *that* is where VcXsrv is running.

```
export DISPLAY=${HOSTNAME}.local:0.0
```

... will usually get the correct IP address. This utilizes mDNS per [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69407064/11810933).

There are also [other techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66398613/11810933) that you can fall back to in case mDNS doesn't work.